# C# Check user still logged with every action (getting info from API)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, authentication, resume

I have a WPF application (written in C# using MVVM) where I start with a login window where users login. When the username and password are filled in I do a webrequest (POST) to our login page (at our coorperate website), where I POST the data, get a webresponse and when the response statuscode is OK and I receive a cookie I know i'm logged in succesfully.
Further in my app I use that same cookie to call our API webpage (also via webrequests) to get all the data for in the app.

The cookie has a expiration date (6h after creation). When i do a new webrequest and the cookie is expired, i need to show the login page again. After login the app has to resume where it left off.

I know i have to change my app so it doesn't start with the login page, but with the main page and check if there's is a cookie (and it's not expired). 
At launch there isn't a cookie set so it will show the login page.

But how do i save the application when the cookie is expired (and i do a new webrequest), show the same login page & process login (overwriting the cookie) and resume where i left off (re do the webrequest)?
And how do I give notice to the main page from another page that the login page needs to show?

Comment: There are tons of considerations when it comes to writing authentication/authorisation- I'd suggest using OAuth2 (https://oauth.net/2/ and https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) to manage all this complexity for you.

Answer (score 1):

WPF isn't a web app. You have state in the desktop app unless you throw it away somehow.
Pages are an anachronism in wpf terms.
Few teams use them, partly because backward forward and breadcrumbs have no particular usage.
In your case you could potentially use the journal of a frame.
I still probably wouldn't though.

I'd do this as a single window app with usercontrols presented in a contentcontrol for the navigation. Usercontrols not pages.  Contentcontrol not frame.

Using MVVM you can navigate using viewmodel first. Templating the viewmodel you bind to the content of a contentcontrol into a view.
Retain a reference to the viewmodel and you retain state.

You'd need some sort of timer ticking down so at 6h you know that's time to login again.

That'd be referenced in the mainwindow's viewmodel.
When the timer hits zero it stashes a reference to whichever viewmodel is current and "navigates" to the login page. Once finished the process in the loginviewmodel then tells the mainwindowviewmodel it's done.
I'd probably use mvvmlight messenger for that.  It uses the pub/sub pattern.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26070.communicating-between-classes.aspx

This is a very simplistic illustration of viewmodel first navigation:

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}">
        <local:UserUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Login Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}"
                />
        <Button Content="User Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}"
                />
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                    />
</Grid>
```

viewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object currentViewModel;

    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set { currentViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private RelayCommand<Type> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Type> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return navigateCommand
              ?? (navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(
                vmType =>
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
                }));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You could cache instances of each viewmodel in a dictionary using type as key if you want to retain state of everything.  Check if you have one already and return that if you do or instantiate.
At it's simplest you could just have a private object which holds the last viewmodel for when you need to switch back from a log in.
Maybe you don't want to get too literal on that 6 hours if the user is in the middle of something.
I suppose you could also do something like warn at 5:30 and let them choose to log back in for another 6 hour session.